# Hazelcast throwing Application error: com/hazelcast/spi/WaitNotifyKey

Tags: java, hazelcast

When a new node is redeployed following error happens on other nodes throwing:

```
Application error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/spi/WaitNotifyKey
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapDataSerializerHook$2.createNew(MapDataSerializerHook.java:75) ~[backend-0.5.jar:na]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapDataSerializerHook$2.createNew(MapDataSerializerHook.java:73) ~[backend-0.5.jar:na]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ArrayDataSerializableFactory.create(ArrayDataSerializableFactory.java:42) ~[backend-0.5.jar:na]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:111) ~[backend-0.5.jar:na]
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:47) ~[backend-0.5.jar:na]
```

All that is currently stored in the Maps are Strings (objects serialized to JSONs) ... any clue what might be causing this?

**EDIT**

To clarify ... Hazelcast runs inside an embedded Jetty server.
When Jetty is shut down the hazelcast instance is also stopped:

```
instance.shutdown();
```

Meanwhile I have set following setting to:

```
<map name="*">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
</map>
```

and it seems to have solved the problem.

Not sure why a simple String would make problems when it is:

```
 <map name="*">
     <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
 </map>
```

Comment: what's is your environment like? any application server? OSGi container?

Comment: Hazelcast is running in an embedded Jetty server ... nothing fancy ... storing strings only ...

Comment: What do you mean by "redeploying a new node"? Stopping-starting embedded Jetty?